# Crear pdf con php7

Tags: php, pdf

¿Sabéis de alguna forma de crear pdf desde php tipo fpdf pero para php7?
o quizás algo que genere xls o similares.

Estoy mirando por internet y todo es para php 5 :_(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podrias utilizar [**MPDF**](https://mpdf.github.io/) para generar archivos pdf partiendo de una maquetacion en html.

Este seria un ejemplo de su uso.

```
<?php
  require('MPDF57/mpdf.php'); //importas las libreria
$html=' <html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
           <h1>Encabezado en pdf<h1>
          </body>
         </html>
      '//creas una variable y dentro pones tu html
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4'); //creas el obj y le das formato al documento
$mpdf->writeHTML($html); //imprimes la variable $html que contiene tu HTML
$mpdf->Output('pruebA.pdf','I');//Salida del documento
?>
```

Comment: Si funciona bajo php7 seria genial. En la web pone que php 5 pero voy a probar por si las moscas. Mil gracias

Comment: Llamame rubio, pero soy incapaz de descargar la versión estable. ¿Sabes donde esta?

Comment: http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

Comment: ¡¡Funciona <3!! Mil gracias

Comment: Que bueno que te funciono @Killpe, marca la respuesta para cerrar la pregunta. saludos!

Comment: MPDF soporta PHP 7 ? Ya que en mi servidor al comenzar un análisis encuentra Warning eso preocupa !

Comment: Si, aunque depende que versión de mpdf uses. Yo creo recordar que uso la 6 que es compatible con php7.1 y la 7 es compatible con Php7.2